# Biased estimation of $\mu^2$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expectation, parameter-estimation

I'm a master's student in mathematics taking my first actual probability and stats class, and I have the misfortune of having a professor who is sloppy (his homeworks are riddled with typos which sometimes change the question) and unresponsive.

One question on our exam review sheet is, I think, in this camp. I'm trying to figure out what the question is trying to ask. Because my background in stats is weak at best, I can't quite guess with confidence what this is supposed to be.

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$. Show that $\sum x_i^2$ is a biased estimator of $\mu^2$.

So the reason I'm confused is because it doesn't seem to make sense that $\sum x_i^2$ *would* be a good estimator of $\mu^2$. You would expect it to be $\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2$, right?

If my thinking is correct, then the process would be to show that the expectation value of the estimator is not equal to $\mu^2$, correct?

I am also confused whether the $x_i$ in the sum refers to the sample. I suspect it must, or the question wouldn't make much sense.

In which case my proof should go something like

$\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{n} \sum x_i^2) = \frac{1}{n} \sum \mathbb{E}(x_i^2) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \sum_x x^2 p(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum _i \mu^2 = \mu^2.$

Since we are supposed to show the estimation is biased, I guess this can't be right. But this also suggests to me I don't really understand the sample mean very well.

If someone could help clarify my points of confusion, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Jensen's inequality tells me that your derivation must indeed be wrong. In particular, going from $\sum_{x} x^2 p(x)$ to $\mu^2 $ was perhaps a little hasty.

Comment: Yeah, incredibly clumsy. All my mental energy was spent trying to convince myself the question was posed wrong. I'm pretty embarrassed :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mu = \sum x p(x)$ so $\mu^2 = (\sum x p(x))^2 \neq (\sum x^2 p(x))$. So the last equalities of your proof is wrong!

And

$\mathbb{E}(X_i^2)= \mathbb{E}(X_i)^2 +(\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) -\mathbb{E}(X_i)^2)$

$\mu^2 = \mathbb{E}(X_i)^2$ and $\sigma^2 = (\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) -\mathbb{E}(X_i)^2) $(thanks to König's formula).

so $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = \mu^2 + \sigma^2 $

Since the start of the proof is right,  we finish with $\mathbb{E}(\sum \frac{1}{n} x_i^{2}) = \mu^2 + \sigma^2 \neq \mu^2$.

Comment: Of course. Is there any way to go from $\sum _i \sum_x x_i^2p(x)$?

Comment: You can stop here of course, the sum is called the moment of order 2 of the variable (I wasn't sure if you knew). There is no need to continue, since it will be in general different from $\mu^2$. But if you want to know when the equality is true, you need to calculate the difference $\mu - \sum\sum x_i^2 p(x)$ and tell when it equals to 0. Which is when $\sigma^2 = 0$, in other terms when the law of each $X_i$ is the same constant law.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i^2 \Big) $$
$$=\mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i (\mu+(x_i-\mu))^2 \Big) $$
$$=\mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \mu^2+(x_i-\mu)^2+2\mu (x_i-\mu) \Big) $$
$$=\mu^2 + \mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i (x_i-\mu)_i^2 \Big) + 2\mu\mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i \Big) - \mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i  2\mu^2 \Big)$$
$$=\mu^2 + \mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i (x_i-\mu)^2 \Big) $$ 
$$=\mu^2 + \sigma^2 $$

Comment: You've made an error in your last equality, actually. $\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i (x_i -\mu)^2$ is not the estimator for variance, that is the definition of variance. The estimator would use $\bar{X}$ instead of $\mu$. You've also introduced a subscript $i$ to $\mu$ (in the parentheses, $(x_i - \mu)_i^2$, which doesn't make any sense, as $\mu$ is the population expectation value and isn't reliant on the sample.

Comment: Of course, thank you! That deserves a facepalm. The subsctipt was just a typo or copy/paste error. Fixed

Comment: Ha! No more so than my error in the question itself. That one was gruesome.